# Are all cubic graphs almost Hamiltonian?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-graphs

Call a graph $G$ $n$-almost-Hamiltonian if there is a closed walk in $G$ that visits every vertex of $G$ exactly $n$-times.  So a Hamiltonian graph is $n$-almost-Hamiltonian for all $n$.  Are all cubic graphs $n$-almost-Hamiltonian for some sufficiently large $n$?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, every connected cubic graph is 3-almost-Hamiltonian.
Replace each edge by two parallel edges then follow an Eulerian circuit.

In the case of a bridgeless cubic graph, you can add a perfect matching instead of doubling each edge, which shows they are 2-almost-Hamiltonian.

Comment: Your answer makes clear that every connected graph is $n$-almost Hamiltonian for all even $n$.  Is there a chance that some graphs, such as all cubic graphs, are $n$-almost Hamiltonian for some odd $n$?

Comment: @Menachem I gave the example $n=3$.  Also note that my proof only works easily for regular graphs.  Many graphs, for example an unbalanced bipartite graph, are not $n$-almost Hamiltonian for any $n$.